# What would be the proper HTTP Status code when user exceeds daily transfer limit?

Tags: c#, rest, http-status-code-403, http-status-codes, http-status-code-429

Each user has daily credit limit.

If user exceeds their daily limit what HTTP status code would be right here.

403 -Forbidden or 200 -Success (with validation Result)

Comment: 403 kind of gets the point across. Or just generic 400. 429 might be just what you want though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Comment: If the user has a credit balance and needs to top up then 402 might make more sense https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/402

Comment: Note that the response body may contain a message related to the error reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. You're describing [rate limiting](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/rate-limiting-strategies-techniques). There is a definite status code for this: [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429).

`403` is about security, particularly, authorization... whether you are authorized to do something without regards to how often. `403` is orthogonal to rate limitations. Think of it this way: if I ask to "add item to cart", with `403` I know I can't regardless of if it's my first ask or my Nth ask in some period of time. Done. With `429` I know I can (`403` didn't happen or doesn't apply), but I also now know I'm trying to do it too quickly for whatever reason.

`200` is also not appropriate: naive clients just assume all is OK, ignore any additional detail, and silently fail the user with a false sense that all is OK when really what happened is the server wants to say, "no way can I deal with this now".

A `429` is enough by itself, but smart clients would also look for the [Rety-After](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3) header, which a well-designed API (and API client) should implement to reduce the load on both the server and client (cooperative).

Presumably, if you know how the rate limit was just "violated" you can calculate a value for `Retry-After` that can be fairly precise. You can take a look at the formats in the Mozilla docs for [Retry-After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After), which can be in seconds or a specific date/time. I've done this before and added a "[fudge factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_factor)" to avoid unnecessary new requests too soon.

While rate limiting with this method could be abused by bad actors, it at least helps in the nominal rate limiting scenarios for both your server and the client to reduce network (and other) resource utilization.

Finally, in the end `429` is right for your scenario, but the other statuses do need to be considered. The order of a call (I'm including the whole chain to the API including proxies) returning `400`, `429`, `403` before `200` *can* vary depending on which of the 4xx errors are handled by API and proxies. Ideally the least expensive 4xx check happens first (closer to the client).